# Maximum number of rows in a sqlite table?

Tags: android, sqlite, limit

Is there some limit of rows for a sql lite table ?
My app is giving a error " no such table x..." when that table have more than 6000 rows.
Below the 6000 rows, dont give any error.

Thank you.

This is the query.

```
    db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();

    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT continentes._id, continentes.ContinenteID, continentes.Continente" 
            + " FROM continentes"
            + " WHERE continentes.Continente LIKE ?"
            + " GROUP BY continentes.ContinenteID, continentes.Continente ORDER BY continentes.Continente",
                new String[]{"%" + searchText.getText().toString() + "%"});
```

This is where i create the table

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String s;
    try {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Creating Database", 2000).show();
        InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.continentes);
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(in, null);
        NodeList statements = doc.getElementsByTagName("statement");
        for (int i=0; i<statements.getLength(); i++) {
            s = statements.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
            db.execSQL(s);
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(context, t.toString(), 50000).show();
```

SOLVED !!!  I just find out why i got this problem. Because the files that i use with Data to create and populate the sql database, can´t have more than 1.2mb. So, i split them, and dont have more problems. Thanks to all.

Comment: can you post your query? The limit of the rows is practical unreachable

Comment: Update the post with the code of the query.

Comment: Can you give us the logcat information?

Comment: sorry about that, i tried to delete the other question because was not well done, but dont manager how to delete it.

Comment: Your code & Log does not match? are you sure this is the correct log?

Comment: If is the name of the table that you are talking about, forget it.

Comment: i have 4 tables, and at the moment, that one of the log is the one with more than 6000 rows. the other table that i have show the code, i have to remove data to stay above the 6000 rows....

Answer (score 7):

You can get the standard information on the [limits of SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) but that isn't going to be what's causing your issue as the limit is actually very high. (2 to the power of 64!)

More than likely your issue has to do with how your application is inserting the records and/or the types of records being inserted.

Can you post some code for the application and how it's handling the insert? I can revise my answer after reading through it.

As an added tip, make sure you've set:

```
Cursor myCursor = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA synchronous=OFF", null); 
myCursor.close();
```

As this can really [improve the performance](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous) of your larger bulk inserts.

Answer (score 6):

Maximum Number Of Rows In A Table

The theoretical maximum number of rows in a table is 2^64 (18446744073709551616 or about 1.8e+19). This limit is unreachable since the maximum database size of 14 terabytes will be reached first. A 14 terabytes database can hold no more than approximately 1e+13 rows, and then only if there are no indices and if each row contains very little data.

from here: http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Comment: I have read that, believe me. Just don´t understand why in my code, the maximum that it goes without give that error is 6000 rows. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

There are no such limits, see below:

- [Limits In SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)
- [Limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems#Limits)

It says:

**Maximum Number Of Rows In A Table**

> The theoretical maximum number of rows in a table is 264
>   (18446744073709551616 or about 1.8e+19). This limit is unreachable
>   since the maximum database size of 14 terabytes will be reached first.
>   A 14 terabytes database can hold no more than approximately 1e+13
>   rows, and then only if there are no indices and if each row contains
>   very little data.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum number of rows is 2^64.

Here is the [limitation page](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html).

Comment: yes, but the limit is not 6000 rows. So, what i dont understand is why the app dont create a table with more than 6000 rows.

Comment: Your comment seems different than your question. Are you getting the problem when you are generating the table or when quering the table? Logcat would be helpful.

Comment: Have you created the table before you try to query? Ensure that the table you are trying to reference is actually created.

Comment: that is my problem. if the table have less than 6000 rows, everything works...if the table have more than 6000 rows gives that error. So, what i dont understand is what is the diference of having more or less that 6000 rows. sorry about my bad english.